# Print values of ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> that are not contained in another ArrayList<ArrayList<~>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iterator, contains

I'm attempting to iterate through two `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`  named `list` and `list2` and print the results while removing the duplicates.

`list` contains:

```
[[4], [3], [0,2,1]]
```

and `list2` contains:

```
[[2,3], [0], [1], [4], []]
```

My current code looks like:

```
//size=list.size();
Integer temp1;

for(int num=0;num<size;num++){
    System.out.print(list.get(num)+" ");
    temp1=list.get(num).get(0);
    System.out.println(list2.get(temp1));
}
```

For each value in list position 0, I want to check the position in `list2` and print the contents without printing the value that may be in list as well.
For example, currently my output looks like below and for the third line I want to be able to print just the 3 in [2,3] as the value 2 is in [0,2,1].

```
[4] []
[3] [4]
[0, 2, 1] [2,3]
```

I'm unsure as to how to efficiently remove the duplicate values and print just the unique value.

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example, what are `list` and `list2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you save sublist from `list` in temporal array and print it out what you already did:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp;
temp = list.get(num);
System.out.print(list.get(num)+" ");
```

Take `temp1` and get sublist from `list2` to be able to compare and remove duplicates:

```
temp1=list.get(num).get(0);
ArrayList<Integer> list2sub = list2.get(temp1);
```

Iterate over `temp` list and remove all duplicates from `list2sub` and print `list2sub` out:

```
for (Integer element : temp) {
    list2sub.remove(element);
}
System.out.println(list2sub);
```

Finally it should look something like this:

```
int size=list.size();
Integer temp1;
for(int num=0;num<size;num++){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp;
    temp = list.get(num);
    System.out.print(list.get(num)+" ");
    temp1=list.get(num).get(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> list2sub = list2.get(temp1);
    for (Integer element : temp) {
        list2sub.remove(element);
    }
    System.out.println(list2sub);
}
```

And output is this:

```
[4] []
[3] [4]
[0, 2, 1] [3]
```

If you are not allowed to change values in sublists i.e. doing `.remove` then you would just put it in another `temp` array list and print it out instead of modifying `list2sub`.